# SignalR 2 connection not being persisted

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub

I've set up a sample SignalR hub, ChatHub, added list of connections. When it runs OnConnected I see it being add to the List. However when I open that page in another browser (expecting the list to have 2 connections now I see 0 connections in my list). Is ChatHub instantiated per request?

```
    List<string> connections = new List<string>();
    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        connections.Add(Context.ConnectionId);
        return base.OnConnected();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes a Hub instance is created for each request.

[specifically](https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server):

> You don't instantiate the Hub class or call its methods from your own
>   code on the server; all that is done for you by the SignalR Hubs
>   pipeline. **SignalR creates a new instance of your Hub class each time
>   it needs to handle a Hub operation** such as when a client connects,
>   disconnects, or makes a method call to the server.